# flask with web uwsgi and nginx not able to run index.html

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi

I m very new in flask, try to run a web application with backend as flask. My project folder structure is
~myproject/
~myproject/app (flask api)
~myproject/web (index.html)

running using uwsgi and nginx
**uwsgi.ini**

```
[uwsgi]
vhost = true
socket = /tmp/flask.sock
venv = /flask_app/.env
chdir = /flask_app/app
module = app
callable = app
```

**nginx.conf**

```
upstream flask_server {
ip_hash;
server 0.0.0.0;
}


server {
listen 80;
server_tokens off;
server_name _;
root /flask_app/web;
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
charset utf-8;
client_max_body_size 75M;

 location / {
     #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
     include uwsgi_params;
     uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/flask.sock;
 }

 #location /static {
 #    alias /flask_app/static;
 #}

 location /flask/ {
     proxy_redirect off;
     proxy_pass http://flask_server;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 }

}
```

But index.html is not loading , it is only allowing api url (like: 127.0.0.1/login)?

Comment: Can't use template to render as per requirement

Comment: Why are you using both `proxy_pass` and `uwsgi_pass`

Comment: I removed proxy_pass later, but still not able to load dashboard on url hit, can you please help to by rewrite the whole config file

Answer (score 0):

This directive tells Nginx just to send everything matching that location block to the upstream server `uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/flask.sock`

If you want to serve just index.html and pass everything else upstream then you could change it like this:

```
 location / {
     try_files $uri/index.html @upstream;
     }

 location @upstream {
     include uwsgi_params;
     uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/flask.sock;
     }
```

Comment: It only load index.html but not able to link css and js files. My requirement is to load dashboard whenever I hit 127.0.0.1, and want to do ajax call as per request for flask api